# outputbufferindex is -1 always

Tags: android, h.264, android-4.2-jelly-bean, decoder

With MediaCodec API, i'm getting OutputBufferIndex as -1 everytime.
Any possible solution?

```
outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info,outtimeout);
loginfo();
if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) 
{
    // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.
    codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
} 
else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) 
{
    outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
    Log.i(TAG, "op_buf_changed");
} 
else if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) 
{
    // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
    MediaFormat opmediaformat = codec.getOutputFormat();
    Log.i(TAG, "op_buf_format_changed");
}
else
{
    Log.i(TAG, "no_out_buffer");
}
```

Also I've got the same problem with inputbufferindex but by setting proper "TimeoutUs" value I got that solved. But in case of OutputBuffer it doesn't help.

Comment: can you provide more code on the parameters of the dequeueOutputBuffer

Comment: Which parameters do u want?

Comment: Which parameters do u want?
private MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
and outtimeout = 1000; but with any value of outtime, it gives -1 index.

Comment: looking at the sample code at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#dequeueOutputBuffer(android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo, long) i want to know what and how the input for the codec is defined

Comment: codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
  mediaformat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640/*320*/, 480/*240*/);
     mediaformat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
codec.configure(mediaformat,surface, null,0);
the rest is as shown on developer site.

Comment: Thank you for helping.
I got the solution.
There was problem with maximum buffer size of mediaformat.
it works fine now.